# Receiving and editing data in Excel from a google spreadsheet with limited access

Tags: excel, google-sheets, tabs

Good afternoon. I had a shared table in Google tabs, added via a link in Excel, but users I didn’t know started appearing in it.
I decided that the best solution would be to set it to restricted access.
The restricted table is not visible when added via a link and is not editable.

[Google tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dj14c.png)
Excel document is absolutely clear.

Perhaps you know how to solve this problem and whether it is even possible to associate Google tabs with restricted access to Excel.
I want to edit data from Google tabs in Excel.

I need to create a link between Google tabs with private access and an Excel document so that I can edit information from Google tabs (With private access) in Excel